# How to listen for every DB change / query (insert) in node express app with mysql2?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, events, listener

I want to call some function on every DB insert query

something like event listener on frontend
Is this possible?
I using:
"express": "^5.0.0-beta.1",
"mysql2": "^2.3.3"